# Creating an auto increment ID

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have 3 textboxes on my form:

1. txtDepartID
2. txtDeptName
3. txtHOD

I have code that generates an auto ID number for the DepartID. My problem is that I want it to auto increment but it is giving me random generated numbers. I have created a `SQLControl` class where l have put my connection string, dataset, SQL  commands so that I only have to call upon them with every form I use rather than writing them again.

The code for my auto generated ID is below:

```
 Public Shared Function GetUniqueKey(ByVal maxSize As Integer) As String
       Dim chars As Char() = New Char(61) {}
       chars = "1234567890".ToCharArray()
       Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(0) {}
       Dim crypto As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider() 
       crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data)
       data = New Byte(maxSize - 1) {}
       crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data)
       Dim result As New StringBuilder(maxSize) 'Imports System.Text
       For Each b As Byte In data
           result.Append(chars(b Mod (chars.Length)))
       Next
           Return result.ToString()
       End Function
```

l also created an auto sub to call on the function:

```
 Private Sub Auto()
       txtDepartID.Text = "Dept-0" & GetUniqueKey(1)

   End Sub
```

I then use the Add button to call the Auto sub:

```
Private Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnAdd.Click

    Auto()

End Sub
```

If you guys could help to auto increment the generated ID and to start it from "Dept-01" would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Most databases provide an auto increment field, also known as an identity field. Just let the database do it for you.

Comment: If you want a unique string use a GUID.

Comment: What DB are you using? – Oscar Pérez - Im using SQL

Answer (score 0):

If this is an SQL Server. Where is the value stored? If you have a table, then set primary key to auto increment with every row entered.

```sql
CREATE TABLE SomeTable 
( tableid INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  table_additional_column_as_ref DATETIME)
```

this way SQL maintains the unique incremental value for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use AUTO_INCREMENT in your sql script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int,
PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);
```

Comment: Would this mean l no longer need vb.net to generate the ID and also it is an alpha numeric key how do auto increment that